# Reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce

So I want to convert:

**From**:

```
{
  emailNotify: {
    EQ: true
  },
  foo: {
    bar: false
  }
}
```

**To**:

```
[
  {'condition': 'EQ', 'attribute': emailNotify, 'value': true},
  {'condition': 'bar', 'attribute': foo, 'value': false}
]
```

I tried the following code:

```
var fromObj={
   emailNotify: {
        EQ: true
    },
    foo: {
        bar: false
    }
};

console.log(Object.keys(fromObj));
var result = (Object.keys(fromObj)).reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
    var newObj={};
    newObj["condition"]=Object.keys(fromObj[c])[0];
    newObj["attribute"]=c;
    newObj["value"]=fromObj[c][Object.keys(fromObj[c])[0]];
    p.push(newObj);
    return p;
},[]);


console.log("result", result);
```

Is this the way you to would do it as well? I believe I'm not using reduce correctly?

PS: I get the right result! Just wanted to know if it is the elengant way or not?

Comment: If those objects have more than one property, there's no guarantee which one you'll get as property 0.

Comment: They always have one property; I hate `fromObj[c][Object.keys(fromObj[c])[0]]` though!

Comment: Save the result of calling `Object.keys(fromObj[c])[0]` instead of calling that multiple times. Just add another `var`.

Comment: these kind of questions should be posted there http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pasargad Both approaches are good and I don't see any preference...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be simpler with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var fromObj={
    emailNotify: {
        EQ: true
    },
    foo: {
        bar: false
    }
};

var result = Object.keys(fromObj).map(function(key) {
    var subObj = Object.keys(fromObj[key]);
    return {
        condition: subObj[0],
        attribute: key,
        value: fromObj[key][subObj[0]]
    };
});

alert(JSON.stringify( result, null, 4 ));
```